# Uninstall Framework 4.6.2 Preview

Tags: .net, windows, frameworks

How can I remove Framework 4.6.2 Preview from my system? I have Windows 10, in Add/Remove Programs I just see Frameworks until 4.6.1, but when I run a tool to see the version installed I see 4.6.2, and if I download Framework 4.6.1 it says that I have a newer version installed and it aborts the installation.
I am trying to do that due to several errors in the installation of many programs.